# ffmpeg output of recordings composition is longer than should be

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing

I am trying to compose Twilio's recording based on [this article](https://gist.github.com/igracia/581a8dfb8b88aa624c1d456adc6affb2).

I have `video1.mkv` and `audio1.mka` (for first participant of video call)
and `video2.mkv` and `audio2.mka` for (second participant). Summary call duration are **54 sec** - video1 and audio1 have **54 sec** and `video2`, `audio2` have **27 sec** duration. Second participant joins to the call after **26.9 seconds**.

When i used this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mkv -i video2.mkv -acodec libopus -i audio1.mka -acodec libopus -i audio2.mka -y -filter_complex "[0]scale=512:-2,setsar=1:1,pad=512:768:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[vs0],color=black:size=512x768:duration=0.189[b0],[b0][vs0]concat[r0c0];   [1]scale=512:-2,setsar=1:1,pad=512:768:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[vs1],color=black:size=512x768:duration=26.932[b1],[b1][vs1]concat[r0c1];[r0c0][r0c1]hstack=inputs=2[video];[2]aresample=async=1[a0];[3]aresample=async=1,adelay=26901|26901[a1];[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2[audio]" -map [video] -map [audio] -acodec libopus -vcodec libvpx output.webm
```

my output file has **1 min 14 sec** duration (but should be **54 sec**).

When i used only audio then output has correct duration.:

```
ffmpeg -i audio1.mka -i audio2.mka -filter_complex "[0]aresample=async=1[a0];[1]aresample=async=1,adelay=26901|26901[a1];[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2" -map [audio] -acodec libopus -strict -2 output_audio.webm
```

only video and combine audio and video also has correct duration:

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mkv -i video2.mkv -filter_complex "[0]scale=512:-2,setsar=1:1,pad=512:768:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[vs0],color=black:size=512x768:duration=0.189[b0],[b0][vs0]concat[r0c0]; [1]scale=512:-2,setsar=1:1,pad=512:768:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[vs1],color=black:size=512x768:duration=26.932[b1],[b1][vs1]concat[r0c1];[r0c0][r0c1]hstack=inputs=2" -vcodec libvpx output_video.webm



ffmpeg -i output_video.webm -i output_audio.webm -c copy output.webm
```

What is wrong with my first command?